# Supabase: How to filter data from foreign tables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, supabase

hello I wish you a nice day

I need help, I want to filter a relational column, I am using Supabase.

In the documentation it says that you can find all the rows in the column that satisfy the filter. [.filter()](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/filter) This is the example that comes out:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
   .from('cities')
   .select('name, countries ( name )')
   .filter('countries.name', 'in', '("France","Japan")')
```

In my case I have a main table called "users" from where I have a field called "time_work" in which I relate it to my secondary table called "activity-tracked" from where through my foreign key in "user_id" I access the fields from the "users" table the point is that I want to access the values of the "time_work" field that belongs to my main table to filter it by the types of the "time_work" field but it doesn't work for me, does anyone know how I should do it? I leave the code here:

```
 const { data: datafrom, error } = await supabase.from('activity-historic-tracked')
            .select('historic_id, date, user_id, user (weekly_hours, three_weekly_hours, five_weekly_hours, time_work) , projects ( project_id, clients (client_id, name), name, status ), task_id, keyboard, mouse, overall, tracked, input_tracked, manual, idle, resumed, billable, created_at, updated_at, username, status, daily_hours, rol (tittle, priority), percentActivity, hoursTracked, percentHours, createRegister, id, indicatorActivity, indicatorHourDaily, indicatorAverageHour, countStarts, summaryStarts')
            .gte('date', req.query.fecha_inicio).lte('date', req.query.fecha_final).order('username', { ascending: false }).filter('user.time_work', 'in', '("FREELANCER")');
```

Comment: Try adding `!inner` to `user`, like `select('.., user!inner(weekly_hours)'`.

Comment: Yes! That was it, I found an example [https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#filtering-with-inner-joins], tried it and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: But I still don't understand why it doesn't work like the way my example in the question

Answer (score 1):

Made an account just so i can post an answer to their comment "But i still don't understand why it doesn't work like the way my example in the question".

I recommend reading through some of postgREST documentation.

https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=!inner#embedding-with-top-level-filtering

By default the Library you are using acts like an `OUTER JOIN`. Which on basic terms means it will attempt to join data together even if the data in another table doesn't exist resulting in some columns being null. Adding `!inner` brings it to an `INNER JOIN` which says the filters on the current table and other table must both be true.

Disclaimer: I am in a learning process of postgres and databases in general. This is just the gist that got me by and am only now going deeper into databases. Let me just say outer joins get super interesting from my perspective.

On a quick search i found this link provides a nice introduction to the different types of joins: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sql-join-types-inner-join-vs-outer-join-example/